# Really? A Riley?

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix is disliked by children,
My infix you will need to obtain,
My suffix is governed by a sheepish male,
My whole disagrees with the children.

**What am I?**

HINT1

> The title is **not** a clue.

HINT2

> To figure out the suffix, cast your eyes upwards.

HINT3

> The "children" mentioned in the clue for the *whole* word are the same children from the prefix clue. In other words, it is self-referential. (This was meant as an attempt for the "reusing information" challenge but I didn't think it was particularly up to scratch.)

Comment: May you add a hint, I'm curious to see the answer :)

Comment: I was thinking Rot13(orqpbire). The prefix, suffix and last line have clear-ish explanation, and infix is Rot13(pb) which stands for Rot13(pbapragengvba) for the riddle? Doesn't explain the title though :\

Comment: @user477343 No guesses correct unfortunately. And on this occasion, the title is not a clue. Just a catchy afterthought I'm afraid.

Comment: @Astralbee so... what could hint two mean? (ROT13) Itqz U xaawqp gb, yk tmud ad qkqndaie OAHQDqp yk qkqe... ngf "nqpoahqd" uez'f ftq mzeiqd... U omz'f ftuzw ar mzk aftqd iadpe qzpuzs iuft "oahqd" mbmdf rday "naaw-oahqd", mzp U paz'f qhqz ftuzw ftmf'e dqmxxk m iadp! Hmmmm...

Comment: @user477343 That was ROT14 btw! Well, I don't have any hair, so I don't have that problem. Have a think about what one might see by gazing upwards.

Comment: @Astralbee it was? Hahah, woops. Sorry :P **Edit:** Okay, so... when people look up, they see the Rot13(fxl. Naq fxl eulzrf jvgu ful, naq furrcvfu ersref gb furrcf juvpu ybbx yvxr pybhqf)?

Comment: @user477343 ROT13 Lrf furrc qb ybbx yvxr pybhqf, ohg guvf vfa'g whfg nal byq furrc. Unir n guvax.

Comment: @Astralbee is it (ROT13) pbhagvat furrc? Qernzf? Lbh gbyq zr gb "unir n guvax" naq guvaxvat vf qbar va gur zvaq, yvxr qernzvat.

Comment: @user477343 This is getting flagged as an "extended discussion" now. I think perhaps you've asked for too many additional clues. If you can work your reasoning into a complete answer then why not attempt an answer?

Comment: Okay. I will try to put this into an answer if I can. Last comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, a bit of a stretch here, but I think have parts of it:

My prefix is disliked by children

> VEG  (short for vegetable)

My infix you will need to obtain,

> GET  (meaning to obtain)

My suffix is governed by a sheepish male,

> The skyward male sheep must be Aries the Ram.  My only guess to complete this riddle is that the area 'governed' by ARIES could be referred to as ARIAN

My whole disagrees with the children.

> This gives us 'VEGETARIAN' which is appropriately in disagreement with the children from clue one

Comment: 100% correct my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Work in progress. Not sure about anything:

My prefix is disliked by children,

> parsley? pepper?
>  try 2: **fi**sh

My infix you will need to obtain,

> result?
>  try 2: **an**swer

My suffix is governed by a sheepish male,

> sky or heaven - hint was "cast your eyes upwards". God is often referred to as shepherd. sun?
>  try 2: **ce**iling

My whole disagrees with the children.

> person?
>  try 2: fiance?

Comment: Sadly nothing correct; however you're on the right lines with the *prefix*. Keep thinking!

Comment: I like my second attempt so much. Probably not right though XD